# X server not running on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg, 64-bit, lightdm

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my AMD64 desktop. The problem is that the lightdm isn't running. If I boot Ubuntu 12.04 with the Live DVD the X server runs, But If I run it from the hard drive its broken.

what is the problem?

Comment: Given the fact that you gave us pretty little to work with, I'd say check if your monitor is switched on. Please add some more details to your question as what precisely are you seeing?

Comment: My Monitor is switched on but if I start ubuntu the monitor switch in standby mode. if I switch to tty1 (press strg+alt+F1) the monitor leave standby mode and I can see the terminal

Comment: Log in from the tty, then check for errors in ~/.xsession-errors and /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling lightdm.

You mentioned, you've got acess to the terminal, so just type in:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

`sudo aptitude reinstall lightdm`

If that was the only problem, this should do the trick.