# Grub won't let me boot my USB

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, usb

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my USB flash drive (Ext2, 400MB swap). The flash drive has 16GB of memory. I downloaded the live CD and I used it to install Ubuntu on my USB...

Here comes the problem:

When I boot from my USB, Grub pops up. Whenever I select Ubuntu from the list it shows me a purple like colored screen and 2 minutes later it shows me a black screen, white text and I can input commands in there... Has this something to do with Grub? Or is it my USB Drive?

Comment: What version is the Ubuntu? Is it server?

Comment: No, it's the LTS version. File name of the ISO file is ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: OK. Thanks this means that the graphical interface should have been installed. Are the commands you can enter the normal Linux commands or special grub commands?

Comment: Special commands I think... It doesn't accept things as shutdown...

Comment: Oops ignore this then....http://askubuntu.com/questions/129627/x-server-not-running-on-12-04 this question may help. There should be errors in ~/xsession-errors if you can do Linux commands

Comment: It looks like grub so try thishttp://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead try this the link was wrong above

Answer (score 0):

Just type exit in grub and ubuntu will boot normally